# How exactly keySet(V mappedValue) in ConcurrentHashMap works?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

How is this method used? What is it used for? Normally all collection views (including keySet()) do not allow add and addAll methods - because I cannot add any key without respective value. Sorry, but I do not understand API and how to use this method. Could anyone please give a clear example? Does it mean that **if I add myNewKey to such key set, then (myNewKey, mappedValue) key-value binding is added to respective (original) map?**

> **public ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView keySet(V mappedValue)**
>
> Returns a Set view of the keys in this map, *using the given common
>   mapped value for any additions (i.e., Collection.add(E) and
>   Collection.addAll(Collection))*. This is of course only appropriate if
>   it is acceptable to use the same value for all additions from this
>   view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Normally all collection views (including keySet()) do not allow add and addAll methods - **because I cannot add any key without respective value**

This is not the case here. Adding elements to `keySet(V mappedValue)` is equivalent to putting in the `Map` new keys associated with the value `mappedValue`.

> if I add myNewKey to such key set, then (myNewKey, mappedValue) key-value binding is added to respective (original) map?

That's correct.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Set<String> keySet = map.keySet("sameValue");
keySet.add("key1");
keySet.add("key2");
```

will result in the same `Map` as:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.put("key1","sameValue");
map.put("key2","sameValue");
```